# Socket.io not using specified endpoint in front end

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to use socket.io to listen for WS messages from the BE.  The BE is *not* using socket.io to send WS messages.  Perhaps this is my problem?  I create a connection:

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io(`http://localhost:8090/v1/my-endpoint/ws`, {
  autoConnect: false,
});
```

Then I connect to that endpoint and attach some listeners:

```js
const onConnect = () => {
  console.log("Connected to APOTs WS");
};
const onDisconnect = () => {
  console.log("Disconnected from APOTs WS");
};
const onMessage = (e) => {
  console.log(e);
};

socket.on("connect", onConnect);
socket.on("disconnect", onDisconnect);
socket.on("message", onMessage);
socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
});

socket.connect();
```

When looking at console, I see lots of attempts to connect to a socket, but its not using the endpoint I specified, but rather some endpoint with `/socket.io` in it:

[image]

I don't get it.  Is socket.io-client only meant for connecting to sockets specifically created with socket.io on the back end?  Can I not use it to connect to any generic websocket protocol available at a given endpoint?  If so, what am I doing wrong in my setup?